# How to access to iframe grandparent id element from child?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a grandparent page that contains an iframe and the iframe in turn contains another.

I have follow code for access to grandparent from parent y read a element id from it iframe:

```
$('#ddlEstilo', parent.document).val(); //parent access to grandparent page
```

but it iframe(parent) content to  other iframe(child) and i need to access from child page to grandparent.

```
parent.($('#ddlEstilo', parent.document).val()); //????
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this solvent as follows:

```
($('#ddlEstilo', parent.parent.document).val());
```